# Why data deleted automatically when added it to FireBase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

```
func addSharedDWSToFirebase(user:String,DwsID:String,gatewayID:String) {
    ref = Constants.refs.databaseDWS
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: { snapshot in
        do {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot //each child is a snapshot
                let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any] // the value is a dictionary

                let DWSValue = ["gatewayId":"0000002028","dws_Id":"0000008092", "sharedUserId":"7rfocieG5KcMLjewgwJlqByg8M03"]
                self.ref.child("00000080927rfocieG5KcMLjewgwJlqByg8M03").setValue(DWSValue)

                self.ref.removeAllObservers()
                print("Data added")
                self.getDataFromFirebase(ownerID: self.getOwnerId, gatewayID: self.getGatewayId)
                Common.showCancelAlert("Success", message: "DWS successfully added", cancelTitle: "OK", viewController: self)
                return
            }
        }
    })
}
```

With using above function I am addding data to firebase database. When data added then automaticallty data is deleted. If I try to add same in second time then data added successfully.
I want to fix an issue that why data deleted automatically when we try to add the first time.
Can you please give a solution to fix this?
Please help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON *before* the write operation, and *after* the write operation? That way we can see *what* data is being deleted according to this write operations. Please make sure to add the JSON as text, not as screenshots. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'setValue'. The data that was there previously gets 'deleted'.

If you use .updateChildValues , the data gets added to the current data.

Comment: .updateChildValues used then the same issue happened

Comment: Ok and when you set your data, do you see it appear in the firebase console? And a few seconds later it dissapears?

Comment: Yes. When I set the data, then it appears in the firebase console. And a few seconds later it disappears.

Comment: And your security rules, how are they?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != true",
    ".write": "auth != true"
  }
}

Comment: so you're authenticated? Because I would think that firebase doesn't accept your changes... Did you try updating it with a firebase sample code snippet?

Comment: Ow, what happens if you use this:  ".read": "auth != null",  ".write": "auth != null"  (because firebase database uses this as syntax, be sure to write / read with an authenticated user)

Comment: When I changed security rules to ".read": "auth != null", ".write": "auth != null".Then problem is same. Nothing is changed.

Comment: okay, what happens when you use the example code: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write If that works, there's a fault in your code, if it doesn't there's a fault with your setup and you have to redo your setup of firebase.